# Ways to make your WCF services compatible with non-.NET consumers

Tags: wcf, web-services

I'm working on adding a WCF services layer to my existing .NET application.  This layer will be hosted in IIS and will be consumed by a variety of UIs, at least one of which will not use Microsoft technologies.

I can make a Web service in WCF that is consumed by my .NET application.  However, I'm concerned about things that work in the .NET world but not with other technologies.

For example, simply throwing an exception from my WCF service works fine in .NET.  But according to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFErrorHandling.aspx), one should approach exception handling with fault contracts to ensure compatibility with non-.NET consumers.  The author labels this lack of foresight as ***The Fallacy of the .NET-Only World***.

Does anyone have any high level suggestions or links to articles that cover interoperability between WCF and non-.NET consumers?

I realize I'm potentially working against the YAGNI principle.  I'm only really looking to avoid things that will be incredibly difficult to overcome later when the developers of the non-.NET consumer report problems to me.

Comment: Where did you see a suggestion to just throw exceptions and not to use faults?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- use any of the WCF bindings that **don't** start with `net` - avoid `netTcp, netMsmq` etc. - those are .NET only
- make sure to make good use of DataContract/DataMember attributes, so that your method input and return parameters are easily and nicely serialized
- avoid any .NET specific types in your data contracts - don't pass back an `Exception` or something like that - use the SOAP (or REST) elements for those things instead
- don't use things like `DataSet`, `DataTable` etc. - they're all heavily tied to .NET
- make sure to properly catch all errors on your service side - e.g. by implementing `IErrorHandler` - and pass back SOAP faults instead (if you're using a SOAP binding) or a HTTP error code (for REST)
- TEST your services with non-.NET clients! Run a PHP page against them, code up something in Ruby - whatever - test it and make sure it works

Answer (score 2):

One good way is to make your services `RESTful`.

From Wikipedia - [Representational State Transfer (REST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) is a style of software architecture for distributed hypermedia systems such as the World Wide Web.

REST style web services leverage the existing capabilities of HTTP to expose the services. Since almost every technology of building software can deal with HTTP you can be sure that your web services can be consumed by any non-DotNet consumer.

A very good example of RESTful services would be the [stackOverflow API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help).

Here are some good links you can start with -

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx